# Pull database table and put into HTML table

Tags: php, mysql, html

Ive been playing around trying to figure out how to pull information from a database table and place it into an HTML table.  I was able to get things working as long as I have a set number of columns with the following code, but now want to take it 1 step farther to where the code determines the number of columns in the database table.  Here is the current working code I have:

```
<?php
    include("connection.php");

    $query= "SELECT * FROM schedule";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
    $scheduletext="<table>";

    if($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $scheduletext.="<tr><td>".$row[1]."</td>";
            $scheduletext.="<td>".$row[2]."</td>";
            $scheduletext.="<td>".$row[3]."</td></tr>";
        }
    }
    $scheduletext=$scheduletext."</table>";

?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>TastySnack - Production Schedule</title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kaushan+Script" rel="stylesheet">       
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tasty.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="top">
            <div id="top-left">
                TastySnack Production
            </div>
            <div id="top-right">
                <img id="logo" src="images/TastysnackLogo.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="split"></div>
            <div id="schedule">
                <?php print_r($scheduletext); ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am attempting to add a loop into the code above to read off of the amount of columns in the table, but keep getting a fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded.  Here is how I modified the code so far:

```
<?php
    include("connection.php");

    $query= "SELECT * FROM schedule";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
    $scheduletext="<table>";

    if($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $scheduletext.="<tr>";

            while($a< mysqli_num_fields($result)) {
                $scheduletext.="<td>".$row[$a]."</td>";
            }

            $scheduletext.="</tr>";
        }
    }
    $scheduletext=$scheduletext."</table>";
?>
```

What can I do to get this to work?

Comment: Insert `ini_set('max_execution_time',0);` at the beginning of your **second** block of PHP code.

Comment: Oh wow!  I forgot to increment $a.... So $a just stayed smaller than num fields forever!  Problem solved!!

Answer (score 0):

By default php execution time is 30 sec.
If you trying to get from DB big data and trying to do loop with it, then script execution time will be more than 30 sec and you will get the error.
You can change it from php.ini configs, or from your script by adding

set_time_limit(3600) // for one hour
or 
ini_set('max_execution_time', 3600);

Seconds you can set to zero. Zero means the script can run forever.

Comment: I am worried my code above is wrong though.  Im still in the test phase and only have 8 entries into my database with 4 fields each.  I wouldnt think there was any way it should take anymore than a few seconds to run through a total of 32 fields.  That makes me think my loop is incorrect to make it run way more than it should be?

Comment: Oh wow!  I forgot to increment $a.... So $a just stayed smaller than num_fields forever!  Problem solved!!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, i simply just missed incrementing $a by 1 for each loop.  Adding $a++; after $scheduletext.="".$row[$a].""; fixed the loop!